# How to break a loop depending on answer from input, then move on with the rest of the program

Tags: python

Hi so I'm very new to coding and I'm making a blackjack game for my high school project, I'm on the part where it asks the user to hit or stand and when they hit it asks them again until they bust or stand, I want it so once they stand the loop for asking them to hit or stand breaks but moves on with the rest of the code which is the logic for the dealer / computer to hit or stand. But when they do stand it just stops the entire program. How do I fix this? The code is not fully completed and I apologize for what probably is a big mess.

```
# Import the required modules
import random

# Print welcome message
print('Welcome To Blackjack!')

# State the rules for the game
print('This is blackjack. Rules are simple whoever has the biggest sum of the cards at the end wins. Unless someone gets 21 / blackjack or goes over 21 (bust). Bust is when a player goes over 21 and the lose. Once it is your turn you can choose to hit or stand, if you hit you get another card, if you stand it becomes the other persons turn. Your goal is to get the closest number to 21 without going over it. The game uses no suit cards. The values of the face cards are a Jack = 10, Queen = 10, King = 10, Ace = 11 or 1 whatever works the best. ')

# Global Variables
deck = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
dealer_cards = []
player_cards = []

print('Dealing...')

# Create the dealcard function to deal a card when needed
def dealcard(turn):
    card = random.choice(deck)
    turn.append(card)
    deck.remove(card) # Removes the card out of the deck so it cant repeat.

# Create the function to calculate the total cards that each player has
def totalvalue(turn):
    totalvalue = 0
    facecards = ['J', 'Q', 'K']
    for card in turn:
        if card in range(1, 11):
            totalvalue += card  # This adds the cards together
        elif card in facecards: # Checks if a card is a face card (J, Q, K,)
            totalvalue += 10    # This gives value to face cards
        else: # This checks if they get an ace and what works the best in case when they get an ace
            if totalvalue > 11: # If total is over 11 Ace counts as 1
                totalvalue += 1
            else:               # If total is under 11 Ace counts as 11
                totalvalue += 11
    return totalvalue

for dealing in range(2):
    dealcard(dealer_cards)
    dealcard(player_cards)

print(f"The dealer's cards are {dealer_cards} and the total amount is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
print(f"Your cards are {player_cards} and your total amount is {totalvalue(player_cards)}")

while True:
    # Take input from user
    playerchoice = (input('Would you like to \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stay\n'))
    # Check what choice user chose and execute it
    if playerchoice == '1':
        dealcard(player_cards)
        print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)} with these cards {player_cards}")
        continue
    # If they chose to stand move on to dealers / computers turn
    if playerchoice == '2':
        print(f"Your cards stayed the same {player_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
        print("What will the dealer do?...")
        break
    
        # Create dealer logic
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) >= 18:
        print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {dealer_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) < 16:
        dealcard(dealer_cards)
        print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {dealer_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(dealer_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == totalvalue(player_cards):
        print(f"Its a tie you both have {totalvalue(player_cards)}")
    if totalvalue(dealer_cards) == 21:
        print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...")

        break
```

Comment: BTW, your deck only has 40 cards.  You need four As, four Ks, four Qs and four Js,

Comment: thank you lol this saved me from losing some marks.

Comment: Really, your `while` loop should run until the players turn is over.  Then, you evaluate the dealer cards AFTER the loop.  The way you have those mixed is not how a blackjack game really goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are requesting is something like this. I wasn't sure if the program was supposed to keep running so you could play multiple games or that it only had to be able to play one game. if it has to be able to play multiple games you run into an issue with updating the global values. to get around this with the code you have you will have to copy the global values every time you played a new game. As you see this doesn't look too pretty but i tried to keep it as close as to what you wrote as possible. There's still some errors in the game I've posted so you'll still have to copy the deck and return the deck in the same way that the player cards have been returned. but that is for you to do :-)

Starting function that copies the variables you already have and return them:

```
        def start():
            for dealing in range(2):
                copy_dealer_cards = dealer_cards.copy()
                copy_player_cards = player_cards.copy()

                dealcard(copy_dealer_cards)
                dealcard(copy_player_cards)

            print(f"The dealer's cards are {copy_dealer_cards} and the total amount is {totalvalue(copy_dealer_cards)}")
            print(f"Your cards are {copy_player_cards} and your total amount is {totalvalue(copy_player_cards)}")

            return (copy_dealer_cards, copy_player_cards)
```

Compare the result with. Here you could use the return value to keep score of how many games the player and dealer has each won:

```
        def comp(player_res, dealer_res): 
            if dealer_res>player_res: 
                print("Dealer wins\n\n")
                return 1
            if dealer_res<player_res: 
                print("Player wins\n\n")
                return -1
            if dealer_res == player_res:
                print(f"Its a tie you both have {player_res}")
                return 0
```

The main function that plays the game with some updated logic and conditions. As well as a slightly modified while loop.

```
            def run() -> None: 
                    d_cards , p_cards = start()
                    player_stay = False
                    dealer_stay = False

                    while not(dealer_stay and player_stay): 
                        # Take input from user
                        if not player_stay: 
                            playerchoice = (input('Would you like to \n1.Hit \nor \n2.Stay\n'))
                            # Check what choice user chose and execute it
                            if playerchoice == '1':
                                dealcard(p_cards)
                                print(f"You now have a total of {totalvalue(p_cards)} with these cards {p_cards}")
                            # If they chose to stand move on to dealers / computers turn
                            if playerchoice == '2':
                                print(f"Your cards stayed the same {p_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(p_cards)}")
                                print("What will the dealer do?...")
                                player_stay = True
                            
                        if not dealer_stay: 
                                # Create dealer logic
                            if totalvalue(d_cards) >= 17:
                                print(f"The dealer chose to stand their cards are {d_cards} with a total of {totalvalue(d_cards)}")
                                dealer_stay = True
                            if totalvalue(d_cards) <= 16:
                                dealcard(d_cards)
                                print(f"The dealer chose to hit their new cards are {d_cards} and their total is {totalvalue(d_cards)}")

                        #If bust
                        if totalvalue(p_cards) > 21:
                            print(f"Player bust! You lose...\n\n")
                            break
                        if totalvalue(d_cards) > 21:
                            print(f"Dealer bust! You  win...\n\n")
                            break

                        #If blakcjack
                        if totalvalue(p_cards) == 21:
                            print(f"The player got blackjack! You win...\n\n")
                            break
                        if totalvalue(d_cards) == 21:
                            print(f"The dealer got blackjack! You lose...\n\n")
                            break


                        #If hit then evaluate 
                        if dealer_stay and player_stay: 
                            comp(totalvalue(p_cards), totalvalue(d_cards))
                            print("New round begins...")
                            break

                    run()
            run()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want it so once they stand the loop for asking them to hit or stand breaks but moves on with the rest of the code"

Your current while loop `while True:` just repeats infinitely. Instead, you need a condition to specify when you want to continue. For example, you could do

```
while playerchoice == '1':
```

Note that this change will also require more changes to your code. In particular, you won't need the `if` statement any more because the body of the while loop will only repeat if the user chose "hit me". The logic for "stand" will go after the while loop. I leave the details for you to figure out.

Comment: He HAS a while loop.  Perhaps you could show him how.

Comment: @TimRoberts Looks like I didn't scroll down far enough. My bad.

Comment: I have a while true loop before taking the input am I doing something wrong there?

Comment: @MythInSpace My mistake. I missed that in your code. Refresh the page to see my edit with a better suggestion for you.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this maybe will work but now it just keeps hitting until all the 'cards' are used. If the user chooses hit once it keeps going until the cards are done. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @MythInSpace "Is there a way to fix this?" yes. I suggest stepping away from your code. Get a pen and paper (or open another file on your computer) and describe in words the steps during a blackjack game. This will help you clarify in your mind what you are trying to do. For the most part, avoid thinking in terms of technical details like variables. You can keep in mind control structures like "if" and "while" and "for" but use these words as you would in natural language. They will give hints to how to modify your code.

Comment: @MythInSpace After doing that exercise, you can think more about your code and how it matches up with your verbal description. You can also use some techniques to debug your code to see if it does what you think it does or, more likely, find where it doesn't. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try it out I've been doing just coding and finding out how to do this for hours now.